# Finding parameter in an execution

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a trigger for my script that when a post gets sent in it adds the email coming in from the post into a spread sheet. Someone changed my spreadsheet name and all the records that came in for the past 2 days weren't added anywhere. I can go to the executions tab and see when they happened, but I cant look at the parameters in the execution itself so I can backfill my data.

Is there a way to find the parameters inside of an execution?

Answer (score 3):

If by parameters you mean the values of the variables the answer is you can only see the values if you have logged them in your code.

Namely, if you added in the code either `console.log(variable)` or `Logger.log(variable)` you can see the value of `variable`  in the executions page.